# Image disappears from ImageView in Android App

Tags: java, android

I am absolutely new to Android as well as Java (only some basic knowledge). I am trying to develop a simple app as per a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=my8PSy2DBsY&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl&index=57). In this app, I have a button which is clickable and call the method `launchCamera()`. The image captured by the camera has to be displayed in the `ImageView`.

**PROBLEM:** I installed the .apk file in my mobile. When I click the "Take Photo" button, my camera starts. When I capture a image from my camera and save it, that image gets displayed in the `ImageView` only for a second (even less then a second). How can I keep that photo in the `ImageView` till the user does not press the "Take Photo" button again?

**UPDATE:** With the same code, I just noticed something strange. Mostly the image captured while holding the phone vertically *rotates itself inside the `ImageView` and disappears*. But sometimes it stays in the `ImageView` vertically and doesn't get disappeared till the "Take Photo" button is pressed again (Desired case).

**My Code:**

```
package com.siddexample.buttonimage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ButtonImageMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView siddImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_image_main);

        Button siddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.siddButton);
        siddImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.siddImageView);
    }//////-------------///////////////


    public void launchCamera(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Take a picture by your intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            siddImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Odd. First think I'd check is whether `onActivityResult` is being called more than once somehow.

Comment: Going with the first comment place a Log into onActivityResult() like:
    Log.d("ButtonImageMainActivity", "onResult"); // And see logcat if its being called twice (or use debugger)

Also (not related) but launchCamera's View view isn't being used and should be removed if it won't be used in the future

Comment: There are also other possibilities where the image could be lost eg, view being destroyed, setImageBitmap called again elsewhere. Since all the code isn't shown, it is unknown.

Comment: You could try saving the bitmap temporarily and loading the picture for the imageview from the file, this ofcourse would be slower but will definitely work

Comment: I have updated my question. I have observed a strange problem. Sometimes the image stays inside the `ImageView` till the "Take Photo" button is pressed again. I have mentioned this case inside UPDATE.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/) , as follows:

Taking a picture:

```
private void captureImage() {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Receiving the picture:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

and displaying the picture:

```
/*
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As @stkent said, maybe the onActivityResult is called twice.

Comment: user2756695 is using code for thumbnail retrieval as found on official guide for doing so: developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html ... and want's to know why the image isn't keeping with the ImageView. Unless the person clarifies their question, your answer is not quite right according to what they posted.